# Post rich text messages through API on Yammer

Tags: yammer

When using the REST API for yammer on https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages (POST) the message will not be created as HTML. Is there anyway to do this from the API?

At the moment I can use this in the body but Test does not get added in bold

string msg = "body=Hello **Test**!!" +
             "&replied_to_id=501448298831872"

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: Any update on this?